# Getting custom linear unique id in oracle in select statement based on Date

Tags: oracle, datetime

I have an oracle table such as this.

[image]

I want to get a custom unique id in the format Mon-YY/unique number in the select statement

The result would look like(see the column UNIQUEORDERID)

[image]

Is it possible to achieve the result in select statement? 
Please help me write the query.

Thanks,
Sajad

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you add a record for some month ? it can changes the IDs of all other rows of that month

Comment: @A.B.Cade -> it wont change..coz date are inserted in sequential order..

Comment: Lets assume you inserted another row: `560, c++, 4/15/2012 10:32`, then it will get id `Apr-12/001` and record 547 will be now `Apr-12/002`. All references to this record will be wrong. I can't see how you'll use an ID that is generated on SELECT ...

Comment: yeah..my code restricts the date to be inserted as previous date..it always take current date time..and the ID generated is just for showing in the UI(as per customer req)..in code we will be using actual request_id..if no data change is done in backend..the result would always be same

Comment: Y3K problem, coming right up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
SELECT REQUEST_ID,
       NAME_OF_TRAINING,
       APPLIED_DATE,
       to_char(APPLIED_DATE,'MON-YY') || '/' || ROW_NUMBER over (partition by to_char(APPLIED_DATE,'MON-YY') order by to_char(APPLIED_DATE,'MON-YY')) AS UNIQUEORDERID
FROM tablename;
```

Comment: Junaid..this would return me a sequence again ..ie Apr-12/1 ,2,3 ..... But i expect the result to be month based..ie in next month its May-12/001 and not May-12/003(as per your query)

Comment: You will have to fetch the ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION ON to_char(APPLIED_DATE,'MON-YY')). But I think this will hamper the performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT request_id,
       name_of_training,
       applied_date,
       to_char(applied_date,'MON-YY') || 
               '/' || 
               to_char(row_number() over (partition by to_char(applied_date,'MON-YY'), '000')
               ) AS UNIQUEORDERID
FROM tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*,to_char(a.applied_date,'MON-YY')||a.request_id UNIQUEORDERID
from table_name a;
```

**EDIT**
Translate this to your data

```
select object_name
,to_char(created,'MON-YY')||'/'||row_number() over (partition by to_char(created,'MON-YY') order by to_char(created,'MON-YY'))
from user_objects;
```

Comment: this would just concat the 'MON-YY' with the requestid...wat i want is start from 001 for each month ...so i dont want it to be Apr-12/547 but it should be Apr-12/001 /002 and so on for April month..